# Unable to set value for Apex variable in Process Builder

Tags: apex, process-builder, trailhead

I am trying to complete the trailhead challenge.
As part of this, I am required to invoke an apex method from process builder.
The issue is that I am unable to select the invocable variable as the process builder UI keeps on hiding the section using which I can select my invocable variable.

Apex Class :

```
public class ProjectCalloutService {
    //Complete the implementation for business and callout logic

    @InvocableVariable 
    public ID oid;

    @InvocableMethod
    public static void postOpportunityToPMS(){

    //Insert a log record to test whether the invocation from Process Builder is working or not




    Log__c l = new Log__c();
    l.LogText__c = 'This is a test' + System.now();
    //insert l;

    /*   
    Opportunity o = [SELECT ID,Name FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :oid];
    l.LogText__c = 'Name = '+o.Name;
    l.LogText__c = 'Id = '+o.Id;
    */
    insert l;

    }
}
```

Process Builder Screenshots

[image]

As you can see from the pic below the UI which says "Set Apex Variables" just vanishes too fast for me to even click.

[image]

Has anyone experienced this ?

Comment: Try changing your @InvocableMethod signature to `public static void postOpportunityToPMS(List<Id> oidList ){`. Right now, it doesn't take any arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your method signature from this(It doesn't take any arguments):

```
@InvocableMethod
public static void postOpportunityToPMS(){
```

to this(It takes list of Ids as argument):

```
@InvocableMethod
public static void postOpportunityToPMS(List<Id> oidList){
```

This should work!